# System Volume Information folder on E drive... But System Protection not enabled for that drive?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, storage, disk-space

I'm running Windows 10, and have a 302GB HDD for my E drive and a 300GB HDD for a D drive.

On the D drive, there is a System Volume Information folder taking up 100GB... I'd like to reduce or eliminate this. My understanding is that this is where System Restore information is located, but: Windows reports that protection is off for that drive, and; Windows reports current disk space usage for system protection is 0 GB. What else could this folder be for?

Using Treesize Professional, I can see that it contains about 25 or so files with names like {95cdd416-1f00-11e3-9d97-c86000bd4dd9}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752} ranging in size from 92GB to about 240MB, as well as tracking.log and IndexerVolumeGuid files.

Answer (score 1):

It's used for several things. One of them is the file/search index system which is the problem most of the time (if you turned off backup etc.), others are [Windows Backup, System Image Backup, Volume Shadow Copy service, and Windows Search indexing

1. Keys Windows+R  (Run Command)
2. Command: control
3. Search Key [F3 ] + Enter : index
4. Select "Indexing Options"
5. Customize "Indexing Options"